# Trying to wrap icon button into container but it is not working

Tags: flutter, containers, iconbutton

I want to add background color on icon, so for this i am trying to wrap it in container but it isn't working it gives me this error.

```
The constructor being called isn't a const constructor.
Try removing 'const' from the constructor invocation
```

here is my code

```
 Container(
                
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(70, 10,60, 0),
                //width: 350,
                child: TextFormField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    prefixIcon: Container(
                      color:Colors.red,
                      child: new IconButton(color: Colors.blue, icon: Icon(Icons.home))),
                   
                      hintText: 'Description',
                      labelText: 'Description'),
                      controller: descriptionController,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'This field is required.';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  
                ),
              ),
```

please help how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

it was my mistake, i was using `const` instead of `new` before `Inputdecoration`